# Passing names of recursive keys to object reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Is it possible using JavaScript or jQuery to set (and get) the value of some multidimensional object by passing more than one key to a function? Since that sentence might not make sense, here's a code example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
obj = {
    a:{
        a1:'a1',
        a2:'a2'
    },
    b:'b1',
    c:'c1'
};


function add_to_obj(key,value){
    obj[key] = value;
}
```

Expected behavior:

```
console.log(obj.a[b]); // 'b1'    
add_to_obj(b,'b1-new');
console.log(obj.a[b]); // 'b1-new'
```

What I'd like to do:

```
function how_to_do_this( key1[key2], value){
    obj[key1][key2] = value;
}
console.log(obj.a.a1); // 'a1'
how_to_do_this("a.a1", "a1-new");
console.log(obj.a.a1); // 'a1-new'
```

How is this second approach done? There can be more than one "layer" passed to the argument, so I'm trying to think of a way to do this. My initial though is to pass a delimiter and then `split()` it, but that seems messy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the behavior in mine you're looking for? It's unclear if you want to only set existing deep properties or create them along the way too.

Comment: Use the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) in your function. Then you can pass something like `how_to_do_this("a1-new","a","a1");`

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles Yes! That's exactly the sort of function I'm looking for. Would be nice to be able to set deep too, but this is more than enough for my uses. I'm interested to see other approaches, but thanks for your help!

Comment: This is setting a deep property, see the example. Could you describe how what you need is different?

Comment: Nothing different needed. You definitely answered my question, I've tested your code and works like a charm. What I was saying before is that your comment on setting deep would be interesting too, and I was also interested in how others approach this question.

Comment: Ah, creating properties that don't exist yet along the way??

Comment: Yea, something like `mkdir -p` in unix. It's off-topic but that would be pretty interesting!

Comment: Nah not off topic, I updated the code to reflect that too. If you're pleased, accept and upvote :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do mine:

```
var deepSet = function(obj, props, val){
  var attr = obj;
  while(typeof props[1]==="string"){
    if(!attr[props[0]])
      attr[props[0]] = {};
    attr = attr[props.shift()];
  }
  attr[props[0]] = val;
  return obj;
};

var test = {term: {value: "foo"}};
console.log(deepSet(test, ["term", "value"], "bar"));
// {term: {value: "bar"}}
```

Comment: Thanks! I may tweak it a bit to `props = props.split('.')` and see how that is

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach:

```
function how_to_do_this(value, root) {
    var objToSet = root;
    for (var i = 2; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
        objToSet = objToSet[arguments[i]];
    }
    objToSet[arguments[i]] = value;
}
```

You call it by passing in the new value, the root object and then as many keys as you want. It'll iterate through the keys until it gets to the last one and then set that to the value you want. This is fairly rough and would probably need some extra error checking to test the existence (or not) of the keys as you go.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/5cb7y/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use like this to set the value in any level

```
        function setvalue(obj, path, value) {
            var parts = path.split('.');
            var o = obj;
            if (parts.length > 1) {
                for (var i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (!o[parts[i]])
                        o[parts[i]] = {};
                    o = o[parts[i]];
                }
            }
            o[parts[parts.length - 1]] = value;
        }
        alert(obj.b); // 'b1'
        setvalue(obj, "b", "b1-new");
        alert(obj.b);
        setvalue(obj, "a.a1", "a1-new");
        alert(obj.a.a1)
```